# deduction from two goals

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have such goals:

```
times(0,_,0).                          % zero times X is zero
times(X,Y,Z) :- times(Y,X,Z) ,!.       % X * Y = Y * X
```

When I try to ask:

```
?- times(0,1,X).
```

I get the double answer :

```
X = 0 ;
X = 0.
```

Possibly because first answer is deduced from the `fact` and second - from the `rule`.

Question - how to make prolog to give only one answer instead of two ?

Comment: You'd have to make it so. Add the facts and then the rules which will work upon those facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a cut to 'confirm' the first choice:

```
times(0,_,0) :- !.
```

**or** ban the 0 from the second:

```
times(X,Y,Z) :- X \= 0, times(Y,X,Z).
```

I've deleted the cut, but leave it if there are more rules.
But I think the 'reflexivity' rule will put you in trouble, with undue recursion.

Comment: or with better readability for me : `times(0,_,0) :- true , !.` :-)